# How to add labels to D3 Chord diagram Group Arcs on arc.centroid()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

So, recently I've started to try using [D3 library](https://d3js.org/). I've successfully made a working Chord Diagram, [here's the pen](https://codepen.io/jeffrockatansky/pen/XPOEaJ).

```js
var parentSelector = '#con1'
var width = '100vh'
var height = '100vh'
var cssid = 'chord1'
var cssclass = 'svgChord'
var labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
var data = [[11, 21, 31, 41, 51], [12, 22, 32, 42, 52], [13, 23, 33, 43, 53], [14, 24, 34, 44, 54], [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]]
var colors = ['#ddffdd', '#fd8b43', '#00922c', '#ffffff', '#F0d064']
var getWidth = function () { return document.querySelector('#' + cssid + '.' + cssclass).clientWidth }
var getHeight = function () { return document.querySelector('#' + cssid + '.' + cssclass).clientHeight }
var svg = d3.select(parentSelector)
  .append('svg:svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('class', cssclass)
  .attr('id', cssid)
  .attr('viewBox', '0,0,' + getWidth() + ',' + getHeight())
var outerRadius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.5 - 40
var innerRadius = outerRadius - 30
var colorsMap = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(colors)
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
var chord = d3.chord()
  .padAngle(0.05)
  .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
  .radius(innerRadius)
var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + getWidth() / 2 + ',' + getHeight() / 2 + ')')
  .datum(chord(data))
var groups = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'groups')
var group = groups.selectAll('g')
  .data(function (chords) { return chords.groups })
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'group')
var arcSvg = group.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'arc')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .style('fill', function (d) { return colorsMap(d.index) })
  .style('stroke', function (d) { return d3.rgb(colorsMap(d.index)).darker() })
group.append('text')
// .attr('x', function (d) { return arc.centroid()[d.index][0] }) // doesn't work
// .attr('y', function (d) { return arc.centroid()[d.index][1] }) // doesn't work
  .attr('class', 'group-label')
  .text(function (d) { return labels[d.index] })
var ribbons = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'ribbons')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(function (d) { return d })
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', ribbon)
  .style('fill', function (d) { return colorsMap(d.target.index) })
  .style('stroke', function (d) { return d3.rgb(colorsMap(d.target.index)).darker() })
```

```css
g.groups text.group-label {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="con1"></div>
```

And now I need to add some info to it to make it more useful. But for some reason I could not achieve adding labels on group sectors on their respective center points using `arc.centroid()`. I've tried to recreate some examples ([1](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c274877f647361f3df7d), [2](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193), [3](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/c9fd848b9410cc543a437b34c266ac64), [4](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1308257), [5](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/chord.html)), but it didn't work out. For some reason, in my case `arc.centroid()` or `anything_else.centroid()` throws errors in console. Also, D3 produces very complicated objects, so I don't understand definitions in scope, when debugging with breakpoints.

**So, here's the question**: how to change my code to achieve required result - drawing svg text over centroids of each svg arc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the way you were trying to calculate the arc centroid; you need to specify the start and end angle, and then output the results in a suitable form. The easiest way to do so it using a transform, so then you only calculate the centroid position once, rather than trying to calculate x and y separately:

```
group.append('text')
.attr('transform', function (d) {
  return 'translate(' +
    arc.startAngle(d.startAngle)
    .endAngle(d.endAngle)
    .centroid() // this is an array, so will automatically be printed out as x,y
     + ')'
})
```

This gets the labels into approximately the correct position, but you can refine it further by translating the letters down slightly (the text baseline is currently at the centroid point, so moving the text down by 0.35em places the vertical centre of the text closer to the middle) and centring the labels using `text-anchor: middle`:

```
group.append('text')
.attr('transform', function (d) {
  return 'translate(' +
    arc.startAngle(d.startAngle)
    .endAngle(d.endAngle)
    .centroid() // this is an array, so will automatically be printed out as x,y
     + ')'
 })
.attr('dy', '.35em')
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.attr('class', 'group-label')
.text(function (d) { return labels[d.index] })
```

In context:

```js
var parentSelector = '#con1'
var width = '100vh'
var height = '100vh'
var cssid = 'chord1'
var cssclass = 'svgChord'
var labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
var data = [[11, 21, 31, 41, 51], [12, 22, 32, 42, 52], [13, 23, 33, 43, 53], [14, 24, 34, 44, 54], [15, 25, 35, 45, 55]]
var colors = ['#ddffdd', '#fd8b43', '#00922c', '#ffffff', '#F0d064']
var getWidth = function () { return document.querySelector('#' + cssid + '.' + cssclass).clientWidth }
var getHeight = function () { return document.querySelector('#' + cssid + '.' + cssclass).clientHeight }
var svg = d3.select(parentSelector)
  .append('svg:svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('class', cssclass)
  .attr('id', cssid)
  .attr('viewBox', '0,0,' + getWidth() + ',' + getHeight())
var outerRadius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.5 - 40
var innerRadius = outerRadius - 30
var colorsMap = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(colors)
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
var chord = d3.chord()
  .padAngle(0.05)
  .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
  .radius(innerRadius)
var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + getWidth() / 2 + ',' + getHeight() / 2 + ')')
  .datum(chord(data))
var groups = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'groups')
var group = groups.selectAll('g')
  .data(function (chords) { return chords.groups })
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'group')
var arcSvg = group.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'arc')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .style('fill', function (d) { return colorsMap(d.index) })
  .style('stroke', function (d) { return d3.rgb(colorsMap(d.index)).darker() })
group.append('text')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .attr('transform', function (d) {
    return 'translate('
    + arc
      .startAngle(d.startAngle)
      .endAngle(d.endAngle)
      .centroid() + ')'
  })
  .attr('class', 'group-label')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .text(function (d) { return labels[d.index] })

var ribbons = g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'ribbons')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(function (d) { return d })
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', ribbon)
  .style('fill', function (d) { return colorsMap(d.target.index) })
  .style('stroke', function (d) { return d3.rgb(colorsMap(d.target.index)).darker() })
```

```css
g.groups text.group-label {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="con1"></div>
```

Comment: Reddit user [takecarebye](https://www.reddit.com/user/takecarebye) in addition suggested [another simple fix](https://www.reddit.com/r/d3js/comments/9hkozo/how_to_add_labels_to_d3_chord_diagram_group_arcs/e6d2nqc) to my commented lines. What's the difference between your solution and their?

Comment: They both do the same thing -- `translate(x,y)` is the same as setting `x` and `y` separately. The Reddit person's version calculates the centroid position twice for each label, whereas this version only calculates it once.

Comment: To clarify for everyone else, reddit person suggested this code: `.attr('x', function (d) { return arc.centroid(d)[0] }).attr('y', function (d) { return arc.centroid(d)[1] })`